# Tensor power and multiplication in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, torch

I have a matrix A and a tensor b of size `(1,3)` - so a vector of size 3.

I want to compute

`C = b1 * A + b2 * A^2 + b3 * A^3` where `^n` is the n-th power of A.

At the end, C should have the same shape as A. How can I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try:

```
A = torch.ones(1,2,3)
b_vals = torch.tensor([2,3,4])
powers = torch.tensor([1,2,3])

C = (A[...,None]**powers + b_vals).sum(-1)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[[12., 12., 12.],
         [12., 12., 12.]]])
```